# How to validate string length using regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex

What I mean:

Example

```
$pattern = '/^[s]{1,5}/';
$str = 'sssssssssssss';
$a = preg_match($pattern, $str);

echo $a; // $a => 1 (true)
```

But I need to validate only strings below 6 symbols length. 
Allowed to use only regular expressions!

Comment: You could add an anchor `$` to the end of the pattern `^s{1,5}$`

Comment: `$a = strlen($str) < 6;`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanx

Comment: @Thefourthbird: `\z` is a better choice than `$`, otherwise `^s{1,5}$` will also match the string `"sssss\n"`.